# I want to restrict user to enter only positive integers and no strings or non-positive integers are not allowed

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I want the user to enter only positive integers. If he enters string or zero or negative integers then it should ask the user to re-enter the correct input until he enters the positive integer. I have managed to code the program to match the requirement but I have one issue that when I enter the string as input then asks me to correct it, then I enter a negative number then again it asks me to correct it, so knowingly I again entered string so it is giving me InputMismatchException as I am entering string for scanner.nextInt() method.. pl help me with this?

> [I want to proceed this way>>output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDiqp.png)

```
 int id;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Your Id: ");

do {
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {

        System.out.println("You have entered invalid ID, expecting Integer");
        System.out.println("Enter Id again");
        scanner.nextLine();
    }

    id = scanner.nextInt();

    while (id <= 0) {

        System.out.println("Pl enter positive ID only");
        id = scanner.nextInt();

    }

} while ((!scanner.hasNextInt()) || (id <= 0));
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The `InputMismatchException` occurs everytime you enter a non-integer value after entering a negative integer value. This is because of the line `id = scanner.nextInt();` inside the second `while`-loop is called without a check if the next value is an `int`.

What happens:

1. The negative int-value is assigned to `id` before the while loop
2. The while loop is entered because -15 <= 0
3. the scanner inside the second while loop tries to read an `int` but there is no `int` to read

---

Here is a working example for your requirement.

- You don't need the nested loops if you assign `0` to `id` at the beginning
- In the do-while-loop just repeat if `id<=0`

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int id = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Your Id: ");

        do {
            if (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("You have entered invalid ID, expecting Integer");
                System.out.println("Enter Id again");
            } else {
                id = scanner.nextInt();

                if (id <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Pl enter positive ID only");
                }
            }

            scanner.nextLine();

        } while (id <= 0);
    }
}
```